# How to train and test dataset and how to convert the labels from integers to vectors in jupyter notebook?

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision, anaconda, image-recognition

Here is my code

## partition the data into training and testing splits using 75% of

## the data for training and the remaining 25% for testing

```
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
    labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

## convert the labels from integers to vectors

```
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, num_classes=5)
testY = to_categorical(testY, num_classes=5)
```

And it show this type of error how to fix and solve it

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-513dfa9190a2> in <module>
      1 # convert the labels from integers to vectors
----> 2 trainY = to_categorical(trainY, num_classes=5)
      3 testY = to_categorical(testY, num_classes=5)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py in to_categorical(y, num_classes, dtype)
     41     """
     42 
---> 43     y = np.array(y, dtype='int')
     44     input_shape = y.shape
     45     if input_shape and input_shape[-1] == 1 and len(input_shape) > 1:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your are trying to run code from the link https://github.com/robinreni96/Font_Recognition-DeepFont.
If you are using windows machine, you need to make one change in dataset preparation:  data_path = "font_patch\\" because "os.path.sep" is "\" in windows.